# How can I improve my buzzer application using a PIC16F1829

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, assembly, performance

I am trying to improve my assembly code (see below) for PIC16F1829 by using a macro to set up the parameters to play an audible sound.

My previous attempt had used a macro BEEP, which has now been deconstructed into its equivalent lines.

However, that attempt did not work; which was the purpose of my previous question, with the program getting stuck at the first call to the BEEP macro.

Since, deconstructing the macro and inserting it within the main body of the code, I get the desired sound outputs.

However, (1) my code is not efficient and (2) I need to gain a better grasp of how to use a macro that requires parameters, which will not get stuck at the first instance that it is called.

The body of the revised code is below:

```
LIST        p=16f1829       ; list directive to define processor
#INCLUDE    <p16f1829.inc>  ; processor specific variable definitions

 __CONFIG _CONFIG1, (_FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _BOREN_ON & _CLKOUTEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF);
 __CONFIG _CONFIG2, (_WRT_OFF & _PLLEN_OFF & _STVREN_OFF & _LVP_OFF);

 ;----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ; UDATA declares a section of uninitialised data
 VARIABLES  UDATA       ; VARIABLES is the name of the section of memory
 Delay1     RES 1   ; uninitialised data, placed by linker in GPR's.
 Direction       RES    1   ; uninitialised data, placed by linker in GPR's.
 Beep_TEMP1 RES 1   ;          
 Beep_TEMP2 RES 1   ;
 Beep_TEMP3 RES 1   ;

 ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Hardware Declarations

#define     SWITCH      PORTA,0 ; Pin where SW1 is connected.
#define     PULL_UPS                    

#define     BEEPlat     LATA,2  ; Speaker pin located
#define     BEEPtris    TRISA,2       

#define     PLAY_ONE    0xFF    ; Keep track of Tone played
#define     PLAY_TWO    0x00

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Constant Definitions

CONSTANT PRESCbeep = b'00000111' ; 65.3ms per cycle

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; RESET VECTOR
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

RESET_VECTOR    CODE    0x0000
    GOTO    START   

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

INT_VECTOR  CODE    0x0004  ; Interrupt vector location
    
ISR             ; Relocatable Interrupt Service Routine
;   Context saving for ISR
    MOVWF   w_temp      ; save off current W register contents
    MOVF    STATUS, w   ; move status register into W register
    MOVWF   status_temp ; save off contents of STATUS register
    MOVF    PCLATH, w   ; Saves value in register PCLATH
    MOVWF   pclath_temp

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; SAMPLE INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

;   If the interrupt came from the timer, execute the TMR0 interrupt 
;   service routine. 

    BANKSEL IOCAF           ; Selects memory bank containing IOCAF register
    BTFSC   IOCAF, 2        ; Check the interrupt-on-change flag
    BRA     Service_SW1     ; Switch was pressed
    BRA     Service_TMR0    ; Timer0 overflowed

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; END OF SAMPLE INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

ISR_END
;   Restore contents before returning from interrupt    
    MOVF    pclath_temp,w   ; PCLATH is given its original content
    MOVWF   PCLATH
    MOVF    status_temp,w   ; STATUS is given its original content
    MOVWF   STATUS
    SWAPF   w_temp,f    ; W is given its original content
    SWAPF   w_temp,w

    BSF     INTCON,GIE  ; Global interrupt enabled
    RETFIE          ; Return from interrupt routine

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; MAIN PROGRAM
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

MAIN_PROG   CODE

START
     ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; SET OSCILLATOR TO FACTORY FREQUENCY AND CLEAR GPR's
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ERRORLEVEL -302     ; Disable warning accessing register not in bank 0
    BANKSEL OSCTUNE     ; Configure OPTION_REG and TMR0
    MOVLW   0x00        ; Set oscillator to factory calibrated frequency
    MOVWF   OSCTUNE     ;
    BANKSEL STATUS
    ERRORLEVEL +302     ; Enable warning accessing register not in bank 0

CLEAR_RAM           ; code sequence initialises all GPR's to 0x00   
                    
    MOVLW   0x70    ; initialise pointer to RAM
    MOVWF   FSR0

NEXT
    CLRF    INDF        ; clear INDF register
    INCF    FSR0, F     ; inc pointer
    BTFSS   FSR0, 7     ; all done?
    GOTO    NEXT        ; no clear NEXT

CONTINUE                ; yes CONTINUE
    NOP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; REMAINDER OF PROGRAM GOES HERE
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Setup main init
    BANKSEL OSCCON          ; Selects memory bank containing OSCCON register 
    MOVLW   b'00111000'     ; Set CPU clock speed of 500KHz -> correlates to (1/(500K/4)) for each instruction
    MOVWF   OSCCON          ; OSCCON <- 0x38

; Configure the input & output pins
    BSF     TRISA, RA0      ; Switch as input
    BCF     TRISA, RA2      ; Port as output
    BANKSEL ANSELA          ; Selects bank containing ANSEL
    CLRF    ANSELA          ; All pins are digital

; Setup Timer0 as the delay
    BANKSEL OPTION_REG      ; Selects memory bank containing OPTION_REG register
    MOVLW   b'00000111'     ; 1:256 prescaler for a delay of: (insruction-cycle * 256-counts)*prescaler = ((8uS * 256)*256) =~ 524mS
    MOVWF   OPTION_REG
    BSF     INTCON, TMR0IE  ; Enable the rollover interrupt to occur

; Setup interrupt-on-change for the switch
    BSF     INTCON, IOCIE   ; Must set this global enable flag to allow any interrupt-on-change flags to cause an interrupt
    BANKSEL IOCAN           ; Selects memory bank containing IOCAN register
    BSF     IOCAN, IOCAN0   ; when SW1 is pressed, enter the ISR (Note, this is set when a FALLING EDGE is detected)
    BSF INTCON, GIE     ; must set this global to allow any interrupt to bring the program into the ISR
                            ; If this is not set, the interrupt flags will still get set, but the ISR will never be entered

#IFDEF PULL_UPS                 ; Enter here if this is defined (not commented out)
    BANKSEL WPUA            ; Selects memory bank containing WPUA register 
    BSF WPUA, 0         ; Enable the weak pull-up for the switch
    BANKSEL OPTION_REG      ; Selects memory bank containing OPTION_REG register 
    BANKSEL OPTION_REG, NOT_WPUEN  ; enable the global weak pull-up bit
            ; This bit is active HIGH, meaning it must be cleared for it to be enabled
#ENDIF

    MOVLW   PLAY_ONE        ; Start with playing tune 1
    MOVWF   Direction

; Clear the RAM           
    CLRF    Delay1

MAINLOOP:
    BRA     MAINLOOP    ; Spend rest of time here

DEBOUNCE:
;delay for approximatly 5ms
    MOVLW   d'209'          ; (1/(500KHz/4))*209*3 = 5.016mS
    MOVWF   Delay1

DEBOUNCELOOP:
    DECFSZ  Delay1, f       ; 1 instruction to decrement,unless if branching (ie Delay1 = 0)
    BRA DEBOUNCELOOP    ; 2 instructions to branch
    RETURN

PLAY1: 
;BEEP     macro  freq, duration
;    BEEP        0XFF, 0X02
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0XFF             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X02
    CALL    BEEPsub          ; Call
;    BEEP        0X90, 0X05
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0X90             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X05
    CALL    BEEPsub          ; Call    
;    BEEP        0XC0, 0X03    
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0XC0             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X03
    CALL    BEEPsub 
;    BEEP        0XFF, 0X03      ; First tune
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0XFF             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X03
    CALL    BEEPsub 
    BRA     ISR_END     ; RETFIE ; Return to main code
PLAY2:
;    BEEP        0XBB, 0X02
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0XBB             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X02
    CALL    BEEPsub 
;    BEEP        0X87, 0X05
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0X87             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X05
    CALL    BEEPsub 
;    BEEP        0XA2, 0X03    
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0XA2             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X03
    CALL    BEEPsub 
;   BEEP    0X98, 0X03      ; Second tune  
    BANKSEL PORTA            ; Selects memory bank containing PORTA register 
    MOVLW   0X98             
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP1
    MOVLW   0X03
    CALL    BEEPsub 
    BRA     ISR_END     ; RETFIE ; Return to main code

; SWITCH Interrupt routine 
Service_SW1:
                            ; In order to ensure that no detected edge is lost while clearing flags,
                            ; the following 3 lines mask out only the known changed bits and don't
                            ; interfere with the others. A simple clrf would work, but this current
                            ; method is good practice
    MOVLW   0xFF
    XORWF   IOCAF, w
    ANDLW   IOCAF, f        ; MUST ALWAYS clear this in software or else stuck in the ISR forever
                            ; Clearing this will clear the INTCON, IOCIF bit as well

    CALL    DEBOUNCE        ; Delay for 5ms and then check the switch again

    BANKSEL PORTA           ; Select bank containing PORTA register
    BTFSC   SWITCH          ; Is it still held down?
    BRA ISR_END     ; RETFIE ; Nope, exit the ISR back to the main code

    MOVLW   0xFF
    XORWF   Direction, f    ; Toggle the direction state and save it back
    BRA    ISR_END      ; RETFIE ; Return to main code

; TIMER 0 Interrupt routine clears the TMR0 interrupt flag.
Service_TMR0:
    BANKSEL INTCON
    BCF     INTCON, TMR0IF  ; MUST ALWAYS clear this in software or else stuck in the ISR forever
    BANKSEL LATA            ; Change to bank2
    MOVLW   PLAY_ONE        ; Check what tune is currently playing
    SUBWF   Direction, w    ; Be sure to save in wreg so as to not corrupt 'Direction'
    BTFSC   STATUS, Z
    BRA     PLAY1
    BRA     PLAY2

;------------------------------------------------------------------------
; BEEP SUBROUTINE
;------------------------------------------------------------------------

BEEPsub  
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP2       ; Set the sound duration
    CLRF    TMR0             ; Initialize the counter
    BCF     INTCON, TMR0IF   ; Clear TMR0 overflow flag 
    BCF     BEEPlat

BEEPa          
    BCF     INTCON,TMR0IF    ; Clear TMR0 overflow flag

BEEPb    
    BANKSEL LATA
    BSF     BEEPlat         
    CALL    B_Wait           ; Duration of logical "1"
    BCF     BEEPlat         
    CALL    B_Wait           ; Duration of logical "0"
    BTFSS   INTCON, T0IF     ; Check TMR0 overflow flag
    BRA     BEEPb            ; Skip if set
    DECFSZ  Beep_TEMP2, 1    ; Is Beep_TEMP2 = 0?
    BRA     BEEPa            ; If not, jump back to BEEP
    RETURN

B_Wait   
    MOVF    Beep_TEMP1
    MOVWF   Beep_TEMP3
B_Waita  
    DECFSZ  Beep_TEMP3,1
    BRA     B_Waita
    RETURN

 ;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
; END OF PROGRAM
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    END         ; End of program
```

Any insights that anyone can provide will be very much appreciated.

Please NOTE that this code has been revised from the initial code posted.

Comment: Yes, a fundamental waveform that is "square" (logic-high else logic-low) is a strident-sounding tone. Seems like you want a more calm sine-shaped wave - rather more difficult to generate  and drive to speaker or headphones.

Comment: The T0IF is left set at the end of the ISR so on retfie it will jump straight back into the ISR. You clear the T0IF at the beginning of the Timer0 ISR but it is good practice to clear the interrupt flag just before leaving the ISR.

Comment: Hi James, can you please direct me to the portion of the code that you're referring to? I do feel that you are onto something. However, when I look at the INTCON register after the ISR, TMR0IF does seem to be cleared!

Comment: Hi Glen, I'm not even able to confirm at this moment in time whether the square waves that I am generating are the cause of the sound that I am hearing, to even start to contemplate looking at other types of waves.

Comment: You are returning from routine BEEPsub  with the T0IF set. You return to Play1 or Play2 where you execute a retfie. You need to clear the TOIF at the end of both Play1 and Play2 before each retfie. Currently you are clearing the T0IF right at the start of Service_TMR0 which is pointless because it gets set again later in the ISR.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the spot. I have made the recommended changes. However, my code does not seem to even step through the BEEP instructions to reach the RETFIE before it exits the ISR with the TMR0IF set. It seems to exit the ISR and returns to the MainLoop after the first BEEP instruction with TMR0IF and INTF set and GIE cleared and is stuck there. Any suggestion on how I can get myself out of this nightmare and in particular get the code to step through the various BEEP instructions before exiting the ISR? :)

Comment: It's usually a better approach to write and test one small part of the program at a time rather than write the whole program and then expect to debug it and get it to work! A good approach for you would be to comment out large sections and keep modifying and testing one small section until successful, then add another small section of code and retest and so on. For instance you could just test the BEEP macro on its own without using interrupts and build upon that by enabling further small sections of code one at a time.